# 21st Century River Crossing

Tags: riddle

In a remote, isolated corner of Chinatown, lives an ancient 32 year old monk who spends her days teaching zen wisdom to FOMO crazed, Y generation, 21 year old toddlers who were sent there by their parents who were tired of dealing with their childishness and incapability for delayed satisfaction.

The teacher, upon finishing the 10 minute "I became a Zen monk in a day, enroll to see how!" course, tests her students to see what they have learned.

She takes them to a 10 meter wide river with a small paddle boat on the close bank. next to the boat there is one sheep, one piece of lettuce, one Bluetooth speaker and a smartphone. The students must transfer the sheep, speaker and smartphone* to the other side of the bank. However:

- They can only transfer one item at a time.
- The speaker is currently playing an interesting radio show via blutooth signal from the phone. If they are more than 7 meters apart, the speaker will lose the signal and make an error noise. It mustn't create this noise.

  - Note that the river is 10m wide at all it's length, there's no transporting items along the banks.
- The sheep and smartphone can't stay alone on either bank, as the sheep will eat the phone.
- The sheep can also not stay alone with the speaker, as it might get startled by it and run away.
- No other items are allowed

* The lettuce must be left alone. It's a test for the student's ability to ignore distractions.

**Are you enlightened enough to pass the monk's test?**

---

Hint for the slower students:

> The master looks at you as you are staring blankly at the river half listening to the music. She approaches, squints her eyes and says in a Chinese accent (she'll later explain at morning shows that this was an ironic accent, not at all racist) *Are you in need FO MO time?*

Comment: I failed already, I ate the lettuce :(

Comment: @ZaniXu hahahah :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I say they

> Turn off the speaker, transport the sheep, then the speaker, then the phone. It doesn't say that the phone and speaker have to stay together, just that the speaker can't make the error noise. The music from the speaker can't startle the sheep if there isn't any music playing (because it's off).

Also

> "Zen" because they turn off the music and now they're just listening to nature.

Comment: Well done enlightened one! Just a note: you can transport the sheep, then speaker, return the sheep, take phone, come back for the sheep. (In case it gets startled by the speaker itself and not the music)

Answer (score 3):

Well...

> 10 meters isn't very far. I can definitely throw both a phone and a speaker that distance. The sheep can come by boat.

Comment: That doesn't sound very Zen

Comment: Sure it does. rot13(Svefg V guebj gur vgrzf, Mra V genafcbeg gur furrc.)